# Angular 2 - Show some of the JSON key value returned from server to client

Tags: angular

I have a service which returns all the product details from the server. Now I need another function that will refine the product detail and show only the required key value. What I did is created a new Interface called product_Subset and entered the key values which I need. Like so

```
  export interface IProduct_ExportCSV {
    name: string;
    cspeed:string;
    maxlp:string;
    position:string;
    xposition:string;
    yposition:string;
}
```

Then in my service class I create this new function

```
getProducts_ExportCSV(): Observable<IProduct_ExportCSV[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.productUrl, this.getRequestOptions())
            .map(this.extractData)
            //.do(data => console.log('ALL: ' +JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

But this is returning all the product values from the server instead of filtering and showing only the key values I mentioned in the Interface. Then in the component class I call the subcribe like so,

```
onExportCVS()
      {
        this.productDataService.getProducts_ExportCSV().subscribe((product_dataCSV: 
        IProduct_ExportCSV[]) =>{
           this.productCSV = product_dataCSV;
            console.log("Export to cvs!!! "+JSON.stringify(this.productCSV));
        }),
        (err:any) => console.log(err),
        () => console.log('getProductsssss() retrieved products');
```

And my Extract method in the product service

```
 private extractData(response: Response) {
        let body = response.json();
        return body || {};
    }
```

Can someone please guide me to the correct way.
thanks!!

Comment: It would help if you also added the extractData method to your question.

Comment: I added that method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will still need to map the required fields yourself in your extractData method, eg.

```
private extractData(response: Response) {
    let body = response.json();

    return body.map((product) => {
        return  {
            name: product.name,
            cspeed: product.cspeed,
            maxlp: product.maxlp,
            position: product.position,
            xposition: product.xposition,
            yposition: product.yposition
          }
    });

}
```

Declaring that the method has a return type of IProduct_ExportCSV[] won't automatically map the required fields for you - it will just help to ensure that you are returning the correct values.

You have declared that the observable will return an array of type IProduct_ExportCSV - but your extractData function is returning a single object - my version above assumes that it is in fact an array as your type declaration states.

If you are looking for an easy way to automatically map returned json to object types have a look at https://github.com/mobxjs/serializr